# $(X/Y)^*$is isometrically isomorphic to $Y^⊥$

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces

Let X be a Banach space with a closed subspace Y,  We define the dual mapping $ \pi^*:(X/Y)^*  → X^*$  by $\pi^* (\beta)=\beta\circ\pi$ then $(X/Y)^*$is isometrically isomorphic to $$Y^\perp:=\{f∈  X^*|f(Y)=\{0\}\}$$

we define $T:(X/Y)^*  → Y^\perp$. we must show that $T$ is a linear isomorphism such that $T$ is a isometry from $(X/Y)^*$ to  $Y^\perp $.

$T=\pi^*$ (with restricted range). Note that for $ β∈(X/Y)^∗$, and $y∈Y$ we have
$$π^∗β(y)=β(πy)=β(0)=0$$
Hence$ π^∗[(X/Y)^∗]⊆Y^⊥$.

Comment: For the surjectivity of $T$ and the isometry property, the Hahn-Banach theorems are quite useful.

Comment: how T is defined ?

Comment: $T = \pi^*$ (with restricted range). Note that for $\beta\in (X/Y)^*$, and $y \in Y$ we have $$ \pi^*\beta(y) = \beta(\pi y) = \beta(0) = 0$$ Hence $\pi^*\bigl[(X/Y)^*\bigr] \subseteq Y^\bot$.

Comment: i.e. I have to  prove that $ \pi^*$ is bijection and isometry?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are on the right track. Actually your $T$ is an isometric isomorphism.

First let me prove that $T$ is an isometry. That is, we have to prove that $\lVert \beta\circ\pi\rVert = \lVert\beta\rVert$ for all $\beta\in (X/Y)^*$. Note that

$$\lVert\beta\rVert = \sup_{\lVert x+Y\rVert < 1}\lvert\beta(x+Y)\rvert = \sup_{\lVert x+Y\rVert < 1} \lvert\beta\circ\pi(x) \rvert = \sup_{\lVert x\rVert < 1} \lvert \beta\circ\pi(x)\rvert,$$ because $\pi(B_X[0,1)) = B_{X/Y}[0,1)$ where the balls are open balls. Notice that $\sup\limits_{\lVert x\rVert < 1} \lvert\beta\circ\pi(x)\rvert = \lVert \beta\circ\pi\rVert$. Hence it is an isometry.

Now we will prove the surjectivity of $T$. Let $f\in Y^{\perp}$. Then by using the fact that $f(Y) = 0$ and $f\in X^*$, we can easily verify that the $\phi\colon X/Y \to \mathbb{K}$ defined by $\phi(x+Y) = f(x)$ is a well defined continuous linear functional and $\phi\circ\pi = f$.