# Does the canonical $\pi: X \to X/Y$ map the closed unit ball to the closed unit ball?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

Let $Y \subset X$ be a closed subspace of the normed space $X$.
Consider $\pi: X \to X/Y, x \mapsto [x]$.

Then for $x \in X, ||x||\le 1$: $\quad||[x]|| = \text{inf}_{y \in Y} ||x-y|| \le \text{inf}_{y \in Y} ||x|| + ||y|| \le ||x|| \le 1$

Does $||\pi(x)|| \le 1 \Rightarrow ||x|| \le 1$ hold aswell, i.e. $\pi(\bar B_{1}(0)) = \bar B_{1}(0)$?

Comment: Not generally. The _open_ unit ball of $X$ is mapped onto the _open_ unit ball of $X/Y$, but for the closed unit balls, that is generally not the case. It is the case if $X$ is reflexive, however.

Comment: @DanielFischer In the answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846988/x-yis-isometrically-isomorphic-to-y⊥) it is used for closed balls, without $X$ being reflexive. How can this be?

Comment: Well, it's a mistake, plain and simple. That doesn't affect the result, because $\lVert L\rVert = \sup\limits_{\lVert x\rVert < 1} \lVert L(x)\rVert$ for a linear map $L$ between normed spaces, but the specific argument using closed balls is only correct in some cases.

Comment: Thats what i thought, thank you!

Comment: Now the answer is correct.